# Why are my grow lights helping some plants but not others?

Tags: grow-lamp

I have two 20 watt grow lights in my basement shining on some potted herbs and some sprouts, in soil, not hydroponic or anything like that.

I grew the sprouts from seed and they seem to be thriving. But I also have a Greek basil plant and some chives, which I transplanted from my outdoor garden, and they don't seem to be growing at all.

I've seen videos of people growing massive amounts of basil under grow lights and I'm a bit puzzled why I'm not seeing the same thing.

Comment: Even in an LED that is not much light , maybe  enough  for 6" X 18" if very close. Less light if it is fluorescent , almost nothing in an incandescent.

Comment: So the wattage is just too low?

Comment: I think temperature, soil, and humidity may play a role (and time. Some plants need night rest. Basil may be one of them: dry-climate plant, so they breath during night to reduce evaporation, and like all the family, the essential oils are IIRC produced just during night). Sprouts don't need light. transplanted from outdoor" when? Shocks are known, so you may wait several months, for a new cycle of growth)

Comment: It requires a lot of light to grow indoors. That is one way ATF  located  marijuana  growers, by power consumption of lights - back when marijuana was illegal.